# How to limit size of velocity output

Tags: java, velocity

I am using java and **Apache Velocity 1.7** to evaluate template

Following is sample code:

```
public void internalEvaluate(Map<String, Object> customContext, String templateText) throws IOException {

    // add custom context to VelocityContext
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : customContext.entrySet()) {
        context.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    
    // define writer
    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    // define logTag
    String logTag = "TestVTL";
    
    // check input template text
    if (templateText == null)
        templateText = "$noDescription";
        
    Velocity.evaluate(context, output, logTag, templateText);
    
    // write output to file
    saveToFile(out);
}
```

However, specific customContext or templateText may make a large output.

The output can be created as file but cannot be opened by editor.

Below are my questions

Q1.
I would like to limit or check size of output at runtime (or before calling evaluate()) and throw warning message about creating too large file.

Does Velocity provide configure or Api to do something like this?

Q2.
Evaluation process may take a long time.

I would like to know progress status in velocity evaluation process.

Is it possible to get progress information?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since Velocity only sees a `Writer` class, it has no mean of counting the output size.

Your best option would be to implement a `CustomStringWriter` class that will throw an exception when its internal size has reached a certain limit.